# Too many image requests on single page making other requests slow

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a page where customer order the products and on same page there are images needed to show of the product and all images are in binary and I am using a handler that process the request and write the image in context.request.

Issue is there are too many images that I needed to show about 25-30 products and request is asynchronous request means images are being load as browser get the data and it sends about 25-30 request and that make the other request too much slow.

while placing an order servers receives the request after too much time and sends the response after taking time too.
How, I can solve the problem. please tell the solution

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe using Caching image serving on the server will help to speed up this.

Comment: What is the server name and language you are using?

Comment: I am using asp.net and server is IIS

Comment: Hey buddy if images that u wanted to show is large in number then u must have to store it in a folder on server. So fetching and retrieving will be much easier and much speedy.... u should have to think about this before you started coding for this page....

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<%@ OutputCache duration="60" varybyparam="None" %>
```

on the page that process and serves the images.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of resolving this image.

1. Caching
2. Using CSS Sprites.

You can use anyone or both of the above based on your preference.